# Manhwa about an adventurer who's secretly a noble's daughter with a sick sister

Tags: story-identification, manga

Searching for a manhwa (maybe a webtoon; just remember it's coloured) about two sisters.

One's constantly sick, the other is secretly an adventurer or a mercenary. They're from different fathers and the mercenary one is a noble. The sickly sister gets real sick, so the mercenary one goes to the noble and reveals that she's his daughter and that she will swear loyalty to him if he saves her sister. The mercenary (adventurer) is highly skilled and the noble's son respects her. The mercenary also pretends to be a man (crossdresses).

That's all I remember. Thank you.

Comment: This story needs to include science fiction and/or fantasy elements to be on-topic here. Can you specify any?

Comment: It was fantasy. The mercenary hid the fact that she was fighting monsters from her sister. Allso the noble hired the adventurer for a job before. The mother of the sisters is dead. I sadlly only remember fragments. It may have been an isekai or transmigration but I am not certain.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour/s of the sisters?

Comment: Sick sister golden hair. Warrior one black or brown; black being more likley.

Comment: Found it. Cassmire : the loyal sword

Comment: @LukeDaPaunch: You can post that as an answer.

Comment: I've posted a placeholder answer, but you can feel free to copy any or all of it for your own answer. You can also accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour] (although if it's a self-answer, it won't let you complete that action until 48 hours after the question was asked).

Answer (score 2):

The querent identified the story as *[Cassmire: The Loyal Sword](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/cassmire-the-loyal-sword)*, aka *Chungjikan Geomi Doeryeo Haenneunde*.

[image: Front cover of Cassmire: The Loyal Sword]

> To save her younger sister Aria from her illness, Cassmire Crisis became a mercenary, wielding a sword and shedding blood to pay for her medicine. But when Cassmire suffers a fall one day, memories of her past life as Aria’s wicked stepsister come flooding back. Rather than take up the role of villainess again, Cassmire vows to protect Aria this time. But with Aria doomed by the story to face only hardships, Cassmire must pick up her weapon once more to become her sister’s loyal sword!